# Symfony Form: Displaying mutliple values in a select field

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-2.3

Im trying to create a list of select fields of my entity with multiple displayed values to each select.

I tried it with the entity type, but there is only the toString value displayed. But i want to display the name, description, price and an image.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('entityFields', 'entity' , array(
        'class' => 'Organisation\\MyBundle\\Entity\\MyEntity',
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'required' => true,
        'label' => 'myLabel',
        'query_builder' => function (Repository $repository) {
            return $repository->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->where('e.isActive = true');
        },
    ));
}
```

Has someone an idear? Is it possible to solve this problem only with the form system? I'm using Symfony 2.3. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `property` option

For example:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('entityFields', 'entity' , array(
        'class' => 'Organisation\\MyBundle\\Entity\\MyEntity',
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'required' => true,
        'label' => 'myLabel',           
        'query_builder' => function (Repository $repository) {
            return $repository->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->where('e.isActive = true');
        },
        'property' => 'customName'
    ));
}
```

and in the Entity:

```
public function getCustomName() {
    return $this->name.' '.$this->otherColumn; // etc
}
```

Comment: but so i can't have diffent style on the diffrent texts, and also can't use the image of the sub entity

Comment: @Flow right - didn't saw the image require.. you need to theme the form - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field - maybe this would help